# GROUP BY custom date intervals per year

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**Situation:** I need a custom interval between dates. The problem I face when I try to **GROUP BY** the year and the result I get amounts to by the given year. I need a custom interval per year from December 20th with time: 00:00:00 of previous year to December 19th with time: 23:59:59 of said year. Here is some of my data:

Table - History:

```
id | date                | income  | spent  
--------------------------------------------
1  | 2019-12-21 17:15:00 | 600,00  | NULL
2  | 2019-12-23 12:55:00 | 183,00  | NULL
3  | 2019-12-30 20:05:00 | NULL    | 25,00
4  | 2020-01-01 15:35:00 | NULL    | 13,00
5  | 2020-01-01 20:25:00 | NULL    | 500,50
6  | 2020-12-10 10:25:00 | NULL    | 5,50
7  | 2021-05-22 12:45:00 | 1098,00 | NULL
8  | 2021-05-23 10:18:00 | NULL    | 186,00
9  | 2021-11-25 12:32:00 | NULL    | 10,00
10 | 2021-12-23 10:35:00 | NULL    | 10,00
```

The expected result:

```
Year | Summary Income | Summary Spent | Difference
--------------------------------------------------
2020 |         783,00 |        544,00 |     239,50
2021 |        1098,00 |        196,00 |     902,00
2022 |           0,00 |         10,00 |     -10,00
```

I have managed to get a result with the help of a loop within a procedure:

```
...
SET @Aa = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM History);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Yr (Year VARCHAR(4), Income FLOAT(8,2), Spent FLOAT(8,2), differ FLOAT(8,2));
Yearly: LOOP
SET @Aa = @Aa + 1;
SET @From = CONCAT((@Aa - 1), '-12-20 00:00:00');
SET @To = CONCAT(@Aa, '-12-19 23:59:59');
SET @Count = (SELECT SUM(income) FROM History WHERE date >= @From AND date <= @To);
SET @diff = (SELECT SUM(spent)  FROM History WHERE date >= @From AND date <= @To);
INSERT INTO Yr (Year, Income, Spent, differ) VALUES (@Aa, @Count, @diff, (@Count - @diff));
IF (@Aa = (SELECT MAX(YEAR(date)) FROM History)) THEN LEAVE Yearly; END IF;
END LOOP;
SELECT * FROM Yr;
...
```

**Question:** I wonder if it's possible to get a custom interval for an annual summary with an condensed SQL query without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add 11 days to the date before applying the year function to get this grouping, e.g.

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 11 DAY)) AS Year,
       SUM(income) AS income,
       SUM(spent) AS Spent,
       IFNULL(SUM(income),0)  - IFNULL(SUM(spent),0) AS difference
FROM History
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 11 DAY));
```

**[Example on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f6863mVdHpPkwn9rKkcYF3/0)**

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to understand the logic. You meant that you can subtract or add the days before applying the year function (which I did not think of). Which in my case if I subtract 11 days to land on December 20th of previous year for the interval.

Comment: I was actually wrong, In your case you need to add 12 days, so 20th December 2021+ 12 days = 1st Jan 2022 so is counted as 2022. Similarly 19th Dec 2022 + 12 days = 31st Dec 2022 so is treated as the same year as 20 Dec the year before. Subtracting 11 days would result in the year running from 11th Jan - 10th Jan.